# How to use formulas in a column of an SQL data source

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to do an formula over an data source (which data is linked from a SQL database Query). I try to do an IF function like:

```
=IF([@customer_age]= 50; 0; [@customer_age])
```

But excel does not accept this. How I achieve that?

My google-fu failed me on this.

EDIT: [@customer_age] is the SQL data column from the query. It's actually on excel column E.

Comment: Are you looking for the Excel equivalent of that SQL query?

Comment: I just want to add an calculated column to the resultset using an function to solve the references.

Comment: What column is `@customer_age` in?

Comment: Customer_age is the column on data connection, on the worksheet is the E column.

Comment: In that case you can use something like `=IF(E1 = 50, 0, E1)` in Excel.

Comment: Is not possible to use the data column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29422/discussion-between-michael-frank-and-fabricio-araujo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Data Column name in your formula if you want. You need to present it like this: `[@[customer_age]]`.

So your formula is going to look something like:

```
=IF([@[customer_age]] = 50, 0, [@[customer_age]])
```